How to Set CorrelationId Strategy for ReplyingKafkaTemplate in Spring Kafka
In our Application we are trying to use Spring-Kafka for REquest Reply Semantics

MS 1 Sends Request to a Topic T1- which is listened by MS2

MS 1 Waits for Response in Another Topic T2

MS 2 Puts Resposne in the Topic T2 with Msg id , so that MS 1 can pick up

Things are working fine in normal 10 TPS load, However when load increases, we get
lot of threads hanging in sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get()


@Component
public class KafkaInvoker  {
 
  @Autowired
  ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> kafkaTemplate;

@Autowired
  private KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyContainer;



 public String sendToQueueKafkaTemplate(String key, String srvMapping, String message, JSONObject headers, String edgereq) {
    String response = null;
    try {
      String topic = aN(srvMapping);
      String requestReplyTopic = aN(srvMapping + "_REPLY_TOPIC");
   
   
      String corrId = headers.getString("messageId");
      logger.debug(" CorrilationId " + corrId);
      this.kafkaTemplate.setCorrelationIdStrategy(kvProducerRecord -> new CorrelationKey(corrId.getBytes()));

     this.kafkaTemplate.setCorrelationIdStrategy(kvProducerRecord -> new CorrelationKey(corrId.getBytes()));
      this.kafkaTemplate.setDefaultReplyTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(this.edgetimeoutsec));
  ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord(topic, corrId, message);
      record.headers().add((Header)new RecordHeader("kafka_replyTopic", requestReplyTopic.getBytes()));
      record.headers().add((Header)new RecordHeader("kafka_replyPartition", partitionId.toString().getBytes()));
      if (headers != null) {
        Iterator<String> keys = headers.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
          String ki = keys.next();
          record.headers().add((Header)new RecordHeader(ki, headers.getString(ki).getBytes()));
        } 
      } 
      Instant st = Instant.now();
      RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> sendAndReceive = this.kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
      Instant ft = Instant.now();
      long timeElapsed = Duration.between(st, ft).toMillis();
     
      SendResult<String, String> sendResult = (SendResult<String, String>)sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get();
      sendResult.getProducerRecord().headers()
        .forEach(header -> logger.trace(header.key() + ":" + new String(header.value())));
      logger.info("Sent_Msg_To_Topic_ACK::tpc=[" + topic + "],msgId=[" + corrId + "],ttkn=[" + timeElapsed + "ms],record_timestamp=[" + sendResult
          .getRecordMetadata().timestamp() + "],partitionID=[" + sendResult
          .getRecordMetadata().partition() + "]");
      logger.info("waiting for response at topic [" + requestReplyTopic + "] ,partitionID=[" + partitionId + "] with corrId : " + corrId);
      ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = (ConsumerRecord<String, String>)sendAndReceive.get();
 response = (String)consumerRecord.value();
      logger.info("Got response for coorId : " + corrId);
}

Is it because, we are setting CorrelationIdStrategy at the Singleton Baean REplyKafkaTemplate?
all threads are hanging in sendAndReceive.get();
How to Set the CorrelationID Strategy for each request.

@Gary - Can you please guide on the CorrelationId Strategy
